# Using sinon mocks correctly

Tags: unit-testing, sinon, sinon-chai

I am using sinon mock as follows

```
var sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
var mockPictureUrl = "http://test.com/test.gif"; 
var opts = { getUserPictureURL: function () {} };
var mock = sandbox.mock(opts);  
mock.expects("getUserPictureURL").once().returns(mockPictureUrl);        expect(AuthController.getUserProfilePictureUrl()).to.equal(mockPictureUrl);
mock.verify();
mock.restore();
```

If we call sandbox.restore() do we have to call mock.restore()?

Is that the correct way to use sinon mocks?

Answer (score 2):

You are right, with `sandbox.restore()` you restore all spied, mocked and stubbed objects inside the sandbox, what is very convenient if you have many in your test, since there is no need of restoring the faked objects individually.

You can read more about the sandbox utility in [Sinon.JS webpage](http://sinonjs.org/docs/).

If you are mocking only one object, you could decide to not create a sandbox, and instead mock and restore the object directly.